# Azure database displays high utilization with no active processes

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using 2 Basic and 1 S0 database (just upgraded to V12). I noticed (before the upgrade) that the S0 database is really slow while the basic dbs do fine. A count(*) for a table with 2 mio records takes about 90 seconds.

I checked the monitoring in the new portal: CPU 55% avg, DTU 81%, and DataIO 12%. This looks rather busy to me. But there are no active processes, sp_who2 displays 4 processes, three awaiting command (idle) plus the sp_who2 process, that's it. The utilization is constant (with spikes to 100%) for hours now.

The monitoring for the basic machines show nearly no utilization (although these databases actually do get some requests).

Am I reading the monitoring incorrectly, i.e. is this a server monitor maybe and other processes I don't know about are using the same server (like in a shared environment)? I thought the server readings are actual values for my instance.

What I don't really understand is the server / database distinction. I can use one server with 3 databases or 3 individual servers but will pay the same price, so the performance does not seem to be bound to a server (I am not using the elastic model).

Comment: It seems to me an infra issue. Do you have a support plan? If so create a support request from the azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I found out that there were three of my processes (with the GUI gone to heaven) producing the load. I killed the processes and zero load remained. Obviously sp_who2 does not display all processes. I had more luck getting process information with Dynamic Management Views: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/